# Fair game probability of a call option

Tags: probability

Nassim Taleb in Chapter Seven of [Fooled by Randomness](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0812975219) tries to illustrate the fact that buying options is misunderstood because we are limited in internalizing the payoff of a financial instrument whose value is usually zero (expires without being exercised), but whose expected value is not zero. Phrases like "decaying" or "wasting asset" reinforce this misconception.

Simplified example in the book:

1. At purchase time the underlying stock shares trade at $\$100.$
2. [Calls](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/calloption.asp) give the holder the right, but not the obligation, to buy a stock in the future at a certain price.
3. We purchase a call option at a strike price of $\$110$ one month into the future.
4. If in one-month's time the price of the shares climbs to $\$120$ the option will be worth $\$10.$
5. We'll be able to buy the stock at $\$110$ from the underwriter, and sell it at $\$120.$
6. Right now the option is out-of -the-money, and it is worth $\$1.$
7. The option has high probability (say, $90\%$) of being worth $\$0$ at expiration, but $10\%$ of being worth $10\$.$
8. The expected value in one month is $\$1$ while the expected value is $\$0.$

---

The mental stress of losing $\$1$ consistently with the expectation of winning occasionally is high,

> I discovered very few people who accept losing $\$1$ for most expirations, and making $\$10$ once in a while, even if the game were fair, i.e. they made the $\$10$ more than $9.1\%$ of the time.

*THIS IS VERY CLEAR. THERE IS NO LONGER ANY QUESTION. LEAVING AS A COURTESY TO THE PERSON WRITING THE COMMENTS. THANK YOU.*

---

Also, given the pain of transcribing all this, might as well wrap it up and leave it since the book is such a best seller, and someone else may look it up:

The expectation as postulated by the author is

$$\begin{align}E(\text{option})&=\text{ potential gain}\times {\Pr(\text{gain})}+\text{ potential loss}\times {\Pr(\text{loss})}\\
&=\$9\times0.1 -\$1\times 0.9\\
&=0. 
\end{align}$$

---

Comment: Not following.  What process are we to assume for the stock?  If it is at $120$ a microsecond prior to expiry, then presumably the profit of $9$ is guaranteed.

Comment: Surely you can't be assuming that the option is still trading at $1$?  how could that be the case?  If you have a new option price, reflective of the current (high) stock price then of course a calculation along the lines of what you did might make sense.  But using the old option price has no meaning, at least none apparent to me.

Comment: @lulu I am trying to follow the book, aware that Taleb is a very successful option trader, and that he is trying to make a very clear point with a simplified example. Please allow for imprecision in my options lexicon. It's an audio book, so it's difficult to retrace the critical points, but I'll try editing, see if it becomes clearer.

Comment: Oh, I don't suppose Taleb has it wrong, I just think you are leaving out critical information.  "fair game probability" of what?  By a simple arbitrage argument, the call must be trading above $10$, with the price approaching $10$ if the time to expiry goes to $0$.  But the old call price has no obvious connection to anything here.

Comment: @lulu I'll leave it open for a couple of minutes so you see that I completely misunderstood (again, audio book) what he meant. Now it is very clear, and does not require an answer.

Comment: @shouldn'tbehere Please post the answer you found for yourself as an answer to the question, not in the question. Than accept the answer. That way the question won't remain on the unanswered queue.

Comment: @EthanBolker Point well taken. It's just embarrassingly obvious, and the product of listening while driving (audio book). Rewinding the tape and transcribing was too much work to erase, though... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Just to close the post - see last comment]

Taleb's comment becomes clear under his subjective probability assessment. If the probability of winning $\$10$ is felt to be $90\%,$ with a cost to buy the call of $\$1,$ and we consider that

> [A fair game](https://saylordotorg.github.io/text_risk-management-for-enterprises-and-individuals/s07-02-uncertainty-expected-value-and.html), actuarially speaking, is one in which the cost of playing the game equals the expected winnings of the game, so that net value of the game equals zero.

We will calculate the expectation with a zero net value as

\begin{align}E(\text{option})&=\text{ potential gain}\times {\Pr(\text{gain})}+\text{ potential loss}\times {\Pr(\text{loss})}\\
&=\$9\times0.1 -\$1\times 0.9\\
&=0. 
\end{align}

And the game will only be worth "playing" if the probability of winning is slightly above $9\%,$ explaining Taleb's comment.